# Unzip binary column from table in Power Query (with M code function)

Tags: excel, powerbi, zip, powerquery, unzip

I am looking for a method to open/read a ZIP binary column in Power Query for information, like the Date or Size of the corresponding file.

I am connecting myself to Sharepoint with:

```
= SharePoint.Contents("https://ABCDEF/", [ApiVersion = 15])
```

Then looked for a certain folder where .zip is placed.

[image]

Those are infos from the main Sharepoint folder, but what I am looking for is in Binary column, information like on the picture below (from Sharepoint), all 3 columns:

[image]

And this a function what I used:

```
// Unzip
 (ZIPFile) => 
 let

 ushort = BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger16, 
 ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
 uint = BinaryFormat.ByteOrder(BinaryFormat.UnsignedInteger32, ByteOrder.LittleEndian),
 EDOCfn = BinaryFormat.Record([
    ZipContent = BinaryFormat.Binary(Binary.Length(ZIPFile) - 22),
    Magic = uint,
    DiskNum = ushort,
    CDirectoryDiskId = ushort,
    CDirectoryRecordCountOnDisk = ushort,
    CDirectoryRecordCount = ushort,
    SizeOfCentralDirectory = uint,
    CentralDirectoryOffset = uint,
    CommendLength = ushort
 ]),
 EDOC = EDOCfn(ZIPFile),
 BeforeCentralDirectory = BinaryFormat.Binary(EDOC[CentralDirectoryOffset]),
 CentralDirectory = BinaryFormat.Length(BinaryFormat.Record(
    [
        ZipContent = BeforeCentralDirectory,
        Items = BinaryFormat.List(BinaryFormat.Record(
            [
                Magic = uint,
                CurrentVersion = ushort,
                MinVersion = ushort,
                Flags = ushort,
                CompressionMethod = ushort,
                FileModificationTime = ushort,
                FileModificationDate = ushort,
                CRC32 = uint,
                BinarySize = uint,
                FileSize   = uint,
                FileInfo = BinaryFormat.Choice(
                BinaryFormat.Record(
                    [
                        Len = ushort,
                        FieldsLen = ushort,
                        FileCommentLength = ushort,
                        Disk = ushort,
                        InternalFileAttr = ushort,
                        ExternalAttr = uint,
                        PosOfFileHeader = uint
                    ]),
                (fileInfo) => BinaryFormat.Record(
                    [
                        FileName = BinaryFormat.Text(fileInfo[Len], TextEncoding.Ascii),
                        Fields = BinaryFormat.Binary(fileInfo[FieldsLen]),
                        FileComment = BinaryFormat.Text(fileInfo[FileCommentLength], 
 TextEncoding.Ascii),
                        Disk = BinaryFormat.Transform(BinaryFormat.Null, each 
 fileInfo[Disk]),
                        InternalFileAttr = BinaryFormat.Transform(BinaryFormat.Null, 
 each fileInfo[Disk]),
                        ExternalAttr = BinaryFormat.Transform(BinaryFormat.Null, each 
 fileInfo[InternalFileAttr]),
                        PosOfFileHeader = BinaryFormat.Transform(BinaryFormat.Null, each 
 fileInfo[PosOfFileHeader])
                    ])
                )
            ]), 
            EDOC[CDirectoryRecordCount]
        )
    ]), 
    EDOC[CentralDirectoryOffset] + EDOC[SizeOfCentralDirectory]),  
 Contents = List.Transform(
    CentralDirectory(ZIPFile)[Items],
        (cdEntry) => 
            let
                ZipEntry = BinaryFormat.Record(
                [
                    PreviousData = BinaryFormat.Binary(cdEntry[FileInfo] 
  [PosOfFileHeader]), 
                    Magic = uint,
                    ZipVersion = ushort,
                    ZipFlags = ushort,
                    CompressionMethod = ushort,
                    FileModificationTime = ushort,
                    FileModificationDate = ushort,
                    CRC32 = uint, 
                    BinarySize = uint,
                    FileSize   = uint,
                    FileName = BinaryFormat.Choice(
                        BinaryFormat.Record(
                            [
                                Len = ushort,
                                FieldsLen = ushort
                            ]),
                        (fileInfo) => BinaryFormat.Record(
                            [
                                FileName = BinaryFormat.Text(fileInfo[Len], 
   TextEncoding.Ascii),
                                Fields = BinaryFormat.Binary(fileInfo[FieldsLen])
                            ]) 
                    ),
                    FileContent = BinaryFormat.Transform(
                        BinaryFormat.Binary(cdEntry[BinarySize]), 
                        each Binary.Decompress(_, Compression.Deflate)
                    )
                ])(ZIPFile)
            in
                [FileName=ZipEntry[FileName][FileName], Content=ZipEntry[FileContent]]
   )
 in
 Contents
```

and this is the result of function:

[image]

Unfortunately I dont know what to do more. You probably ask yourself wth I am connecting in this way, well, we are having daily refresh of our data on Sharepoint and we would like to make Report that is going to tell us is data "actual (today)" and what size.
I would appreciate any kind of help.

This are additional pictures, where simple Binary.ToText doesnt functioning:

[image]

Or even this:

[image]

So, that is the reason that I have this spacey function to do the job, it works if I upload ZIP from folder (locally) but not in Sharepoint..

Comment: Woah! That's really cool! So, now you have the contents of those files as binary, but what are those files? If they are text files you can just use ` Binary.ToText`.

Comment: @JSmart523 Well, have a look on the additional screenshots. It doesn't support none of those formats, I know why I did this function.

Comment: No, not on your zip file, on the contents of the files within the zip. Unzipping gives you a table with "Filename" and "Content" columns, right? From there, try `Table.AddColumn(#"That resulting table", "Content As Text", each Binary.ToText([Content]), type text)`? _Are_ those "*.bak" files text?

Comment: @JSmart523 Hmm I am getting like: 

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

Comment: @JSmart523 I can't open Contents within the ZIP...with a function that gives still Binary that has error or is empty. And also gives me wrong files, should be 2x bak files with Date and Size.

Comment: The Unzip function works. (Side question: Where did you get it? I want to make sure I credit the source in my personal notes.) When looking at the table of filename/content, did you try clicking on the "binary" of the content?

Comment: @JSmart523  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-connect-Azure-DevOps-REST-API-in-to-power-bi/m-p/1105352/highlight/true

Yes I did and this what is written in both Binary files
1) DataFormat.Error: Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.
2) DataFormat.Error: Block length does not match with its complement.

And if I use your step then I got "Content as Text" > Error (cant click it, just text) in rows

Comment: I suspect you're right. Searching the internet, I did find variants of the unzip function, including [this one](https://github.com/Michael19842/PowerBiFunctions/blob/main/ZipFile/Unzip.m) which apparently addresses the possibility that the file size is missing from the metadata, but I don't know if that's the problem or if it's something else.

Comment: @JSmart523 Yeah... and this is what I get as an error:

DataFormat.Error: Block length does not match with its complement.

But thanks for your support.